# Testing for undefined variables in Ruby a la JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, undefined

In JavaScript there's a useful way to test for a variable which has never been defined at any given point. For example, the following snippet of code will return **true** if the variable **bob** has not been defined:

```
typeof(bob)=='undefined'
```

How do I accomplish the same test in Ruby?

edit: I'm looking for a test which is equally compact in nature. I've come up with some awkward approximations using exceptions and such, but those aren't very pretty!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
defined?(variable_name)

irb(main):004:0> defined?(foo)
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> foo = 1
=> 1
irb(main):006:0> defined?(foo)
=> "local-variable"
```

Here is a good [write up](http://redhanded.hobix.com/inspect/methodCheckDefined.html) on it.

Comment: heheh, who would have known it would be so easy. I was doing stuff like:

test = begin
  does_not_exist
rescue NameError
  "undefined"
end

Comment: interesting that defined? blah returns nil and not false and returns a string of type if it is defined

Comment: There are some other options like object.instance_variable_defined?(:var_name). Search in the docs for defined? and you'll find the more specific versions.

Comment: nil is falsey. You can do 'if defined?(blah)'

Comment: I realize this just seems strange because of '?' at the end of the method. I would assume a boolean return but instead get nil or a string

Comment: Just to get a boolean result for the test a good idea may be !!defined?(foo)

Answer (score 10):

`defined?` is a function that returns nil if the item is undefined.

```
defined? somevar
=> nil
somevar = 12
defined? somevar
=> "local-variable"
```

So:

```
if defined?(somevar)
  do_something
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that defined? returns a string if the variable is defined, nil if it isn't, so use conditional checking on its results. I think the syntax alludes that it would return a boolean.

Comment: True, but since 'nil' is falsey and all strings are truthy, you can treat the return values like booleans for all flow-control purposes (if, elsif, unless, while, until, etc).

Answer (score 1):

All the possible scenarios

```
irb(main):001:0> defined? ur_variable
=> nil

irb(main):001:0> ur_variable= 12
irb(main):002:0> defined? ur_variable
=> "local-variable"

irb(main):001:0> another_variable = nil
irb(main):002:0> defined? another_variable
=> "local-variable"
```

Answer (score -1):

Can also test this way.

```
   if somevar.nil
        # not set do something
    else
        # is set do something else
    end
```

Comment: Nope.  "nil" and "undefined" mean two different things.

Comment: if defined?(variable_to_test) == nil  
      puts "variable_to_test is undefined"  
    else  
      puts "variable_to_test is defined"  
    end  
    
    => variable_to_test is undefined
    
    variable_to_test = ""
    
    if defined?(variable_to_test) == nil  
      puts "variable_to_test is undefined"  
    else  
      puts "variable_to_test is defined"  
    end
    
    => variable_to_test is defined

Seems like there ought to be a more straightforward way?

Comment: Sorry, tried to repost with correct formatting and failed. Later